# When to use `strict = TRUE` in power.prop.test()

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, statistical-power

I have been using `power.prop.test()` in base R for a long time, and just noticed the `strict` parameter defaults to FALSE, but the function's documentation says to use it in two-sided cases, which is strange because the default for this function's `alternative` parameter is `"two-sided"`.

The documentation states, "If strict = TRUE is used, the power will include the probability of rejection in the opposite direction of the true effect, in the two-sided case. Without this the power will be half the significance level if the true difference is zero." This last portion about the power being half the significance level puzzles me. In practice I see no difference in the output when I include strict=TRUE or do not, unless the expected difference is near 0 (see second example).

## Example 1 with no practical difference.

```
power.prop.test(p1 = .4, p2 = .5, power = .8, strict = TRUE)
```

```
power.prop.test(p1 = .4, p2 = .5, power = .8)
```

Both return an `n` of 387.

## Example 2

When I compute the `power` of a near 0 difference, then I do see that my power is half my significance level (which by default is .05).

```
power.prop.test(p1 = .4, p2 = .400001, strict = TRUE, n = 100000)
```

```
power.prop.test(p1 = .4, p2 = .400001, n = 100000)
```

Since I would not run an experiment anticipating a near zero difference, when would I practically apply the strict=TRUE parameter?